# How to use flash backend for new Audio()?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, html5-audio

I've made a website, to test the html5 audio. Unfortunately some browser doesn't support it. How to use a flash backend? I haven't found anything useable. The flash backend examples on the web use the DOM element, not the new Audio(). I don't want to use JQuery for this little experiment.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Audio test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

//testbegin
var audioTagSupport = !!(document.createElement('audio').canPlayType);

try {
    myAudio = new Audio(""); 
    audioObjSupport = !!(myAudio.canPlayType);
    basicAudioSupport = !!(!audioObjSupport ? myAudio.play : false);
} catch (e) {
    audioObjSupport = false;
    basicAudioSupport = false;
}

if (myAudio.canPlayType) {
    canPlayOgg = ("no" != myAudio.canPlayType("audio/ogg")) &&
 ("" != myAudio.canPlayType("audio/ogg"));

    canPlayMp3 = ("no" != myAudio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) &&
 ("" != myAudio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg"));
}
//testend


if(canPlayMp3) {
var audio = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3");
} else if(canPlayOgg) {
var audio = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.ogg");
} else {
//flash...
}

audio.addEventListener('ended', function() { 
   document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+= 'ended<br/>';
}, false);

audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
   document.getElementById('ido').innerHTML = '0 / ' + Math.floor(audio.duration);
   document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+= 'can start<br/>';
}, false);

audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
   document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+= 'loaded<br/>';
}, false);

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() { 
   document.getElementById('timme').innerHTML = Math.floor(audio.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(audio.duration);
   document.getElementById('buff').innerHTML = audio.buffered.end(audio.buffered.length-1);
}, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.play();">start</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.pause();">pause</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.volume=prompt('from 0 to 1',0.7)">volume</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.currentTime = 3;">jump</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="audio.playbackRate=prompt('from 0 to 1',0.7)">speed</a><br/>
<p id="timme">?/?</p>
<p id="buff">?</p>
<div id="log">...<br/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) implements the HTML5 media element APIs with only some small changes needed for initialization. You just have to use `new MediaElement(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "audio"))` instead of `new Audio`.

Also, you shouldn't be using code like this:

```
if(canPlayMp3) {
var audio = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3");
} else if(canPlayOgg) {
var audio = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.ogg");
} else {
//flash...
}
```

Just use `<source>` elements in one `<audio>` element.

```
var
  audio = new Audio
, mp3 = audio.appendChild(document.createElementNS(audio.namespaceURI, "source"))
, ogg = audio.appendChild(mp3.cloneNode())
;

mp3.type = "audio/mpeg";
mp3.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3";

ogg.type = "audio/ogg;codecs='vorbis'";
ogg.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3";
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you question correctly, the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) makes this simple. It states:

> Some embedded content elements can have fallback content: content that is to be used when the external resource cannot be used (e.g. because it is of an unsupported format).

You don't have to do an elaborate test for browser support. Just include [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/), [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), or some other equivalent in your page (or create the `audio` element yourself), so that the `audio` element exists in browsers that don't support it. Then include your audio like this:

```
<audio>

    <source src="Path/To/File.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="Path/To/File.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />

    <object>
        <!-- Flash player here -->
    </object>

</audio>
```

Older browsers with no `audio` support will ignore the `source` elements and instead use the `object` element that contains your Flash player.

Modern browsers will play the first compatible `source` file they see, and will ignore the `object` element.

Sorry if I misunderstood the question. By "flash backend", I assumed you meant "Flash backup", as in a fallback Flash player in case the native `audio` isn't supported.

Comment: I hoped, that there is a library, using I can handle the flash audio with javascript, like the `new Audio()`.

Comment: You mean like http://mediaelementjs.com/ which I found by Googling "html5 video audio library" which does NOT require jQuery.  How much time did you actually spend looking for something useable?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using jplayer. Its a jQuery plugin that handles audio and video in html5 with a flash fallback

Comment: I wrote, that I don't want to use JQuery

Comment: understood.  but since it's open source you know that means you can examine how it implements a flash fallback.  And since it's widely used, you can know that it will work most of the time.

Comment: it's just the dom element, not the `new Audio()` function

Comment: what do you mean, it's just the DOM element? The `Audio()` element doesn't exist in IE8 and lower. I don't understand why examining the Flash fallback implementation in jPlayer isn't sufficient..